# Does Visual Studio inject telemetry code calling phicdn.net?

Tags: c#, malware, telemetry

We're currently handling the aftermath of the 3CX supply chain attack, and part of that had me uploading a good part of our prod assemblies and executables to VirusTotal to check if something got compromised.

Next to the usual false positives i got suspicious when behavioural analysis via Zenbox reported various DNS requests i could not explain - the executable in question is a simple wrapper around a windows service, handling basic functionality via System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase, really nothing fancy.

If i compile in a debug configuration, everything seems to be fine, but as soon as i switch to release config and rebuild, Zenbox detects calls to fp2E7A.wpc.2BE4.phicdn.net and fp2e7a.wpc.phicdn.net. There is no single line of code that could lead to these calls, and i double checked everything, even decompiling the built exe.

At last i simply created a blank .NET7 Windows Forms App from the VS Template and just compiled release - and lo and behold it calls fp2e7a.wpc.phicdn.net.

After some digging it seems like these lead to somewhere at EdgeCast and are somehow affiliated with Microsoft Visual Studio / telemetry services, but i'm still suspicious.

For me there are only two explanations:

a) my compiler / system is compromised and injects malicious calls into everything i build

b) MS injects telemetry (?) calls into everything i build

Obviously b) would be my preferred choice, does sombody know if that is actually the case and can confirm?

Comment: I can't answer that, but are you running from inside VS or by using file explorer / command box?  Try launching from outside VS.

Comment: In the meantime i have spoken with a security consultant; seems like i was right, the OS is trying to reach some form of certificate server. Phew.

Answer (score 2):

`fp2e7a.wpc.2be4.phicdn.net` and `fp2e7a.wpc.phicdn.net` are the CNAMEs for ocsp.digicert.com, which is a legitimate service for checking for certificate revocation

per:
https://github.com/hoshsadiq/adblock-nocoin-list/issues/452

Comment: Don't understand why this piece of information isn't easier to find